# ADALM Mk2 Scripting environment not printing to console

Tags: oscilloscope

I have a ADALM MK2 module.

I am trying to do Scopy scripting.

I have a script test.js with only one line:

printToConsole("hello")

nothing prints,

any ideas?

(i call the script with Scopy --script test.js)

Answer (score -1):

I found one workaround, comment if there is something you are not sure about

```
function log(x){
    fileIO.appendToFile(x+"\n","log.txt")
}

launcher.connect("usb:1.14.5")
log("Connected Successfully")


try{
siggen.mode[0]=2;
siggen.buffer_file_path[0]="sound.wav";
siggen.enabled[0]=true;
siggen.running=true;


}catch(e){
log("error")
    log(e.message)

}

while(true){
    msleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: It is entirely unclear how the script in the answer prints "hello" to the console! All in all there is not enough context or information to make this question + answer useful to anyone.